# How to get grid view presence in google search of my website as shown in google search for "twitter"?

Tags: html, seo, google-search

I have my website live and it is visible in google search but I want it to be displayed in a grid view as shown in google search of key word for example "twitter". Can someone guide me how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334).

There's no explicit way you can define sitelinks. It's up to Google's algorithm to decide what links, if any, should appear on sitelinks. Just 
make sure your site adheres to all the Google SEO guidelines and if you some popular links with enough traffic, they may show up as sitelinks of search results.